# How are NOTAMs distributed and received?

Tags: notam

Can you only receive NOTAMs via teleprinter? If so, how do you receive them in flight in a plane without a printer? Also, how is a NOTAM generated? I'm trying to read an Oxford Air Law book and it is so hard to understand.

Comment: There are multiple ways, at least in the UK.  [On the internet](http://notaminfo.com/ukmap) for example.

Comment: Related questions: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33516/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29067/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7480/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/718/62). It might also help to mention which country you're interested in; sometimes local procedures can be different.

Comment: FWIW, in the 1990s at the two 747 carriers I worked for, printed NOTAMs were delivered to the captain with the printed flight plan. Usually they had been printed by a dot matrix printer attached to a computer. However, at some out stations they were fax copies, and sometimes, especially in third world countries they were printed by teletypes.